# Button and size of text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with size of text in button. I have layout where I use weightSum and my button width is match parent and hight is 30%. Everything works fine but when I change size of screen on emulator my text is still small. How I can change size text depend on size of screen?
This is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="30" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There is any way to do this automaticly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sp as unit for textsize of button

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:layout_weight="30" />
```

If this does not solve your problem, create folder like

1) layout
2) layout-small
3) layout-large
4) layout-xlarge

as suggested by Nikhil but along with this do consider [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

Same as folders suggested above you can create different values folder for each screen type

1) values 2) values-small 3) values-large ...

create xml file called dimens.xml in each of them and specify the textSize of your button with the reference of dimen resources as below

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:textSize="@dimen/small_font"
android:layout_weight="30" />
```

This will set font size according to the screen size

Hope this will be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

if you add to the XML in the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="click me"
    android:textSize="22dp" />
```

this should do the trick.

if you want to change the text size dynamically, you should get the screen size and then set the textSize with `button.setTextSize(size);`

Answer (score 1):

For Diffrent screens there are diffrent layout in android if you want to make UI looks for all Screens then you have to make 4 folder for layout

```
1) layout
2) layout-small
3) layout-large
4) layout-xlarge
```

for more information u may refer this link :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score -3):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:layout_weight="30" />
```