# TextView FontSize according to Different Resolution and ScreenSize

Tags: android, textview, font-size

Here i develop one Android application, which can run on all screen size and resolution devices. But one problem is there my `TextView's` Fontsize is same on all the Screen-Size. I want to change `FontSize` according to Different `ScreenSize` and Screen Resolution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595795/button-and-size-of-text/10596355#10596355](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595795/button-and-size-of-text/10596355#10596355)

Comment: 1. use **sp**
2. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-devices

Answer (score 5):

Use the code  from [Screen Category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/determine-device-screen-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-using-code) or use [getSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29) method like:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions) to get the screen size and and then set the font size accordingly using **setTextSize()** method, you can also consider using [sp](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) unit for font size.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you have not done so already, you should read this

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

To provide any resource, including styles that could apply to text, you should read the section [Using configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Another useful document here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension should help you with selecting the right unit of measure for text, ideally you want to use sp's as explained in the excerpt:

> sp
>
> Scale-independent Pixels - This is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you
>   use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for
>   both the screen density and the user's preference.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hi create the folders as below in your resources folder and then copy your XML files in to it now you can check the palette window it will show the screens for different sizes based on that u can modify the screen size .

**layout-large, layout-small, layout-xlarge ,**

Now it supports to all types of screen sizes and your Font size will be clear based on screen size. For more information regarding to Supporting Multiple Screens check the android **[documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)** .

Answer (score 1):

**automatic adjust font size as per screen by using this code**

```
Display display;
Point size;
int width, height;
float txtsize;
```

declare  and use in oncreate()

```
display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
         size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
         width = size.x;
         height = size.y;
         txtsize=height*0.024f;
```

/* if your screen height is 854 its use font size 20.4*/

to set size to textview just use this code..

```
 textView.setTextSize(txtsize);
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is make necessary folders like layout-large, layout-small, layout-normal,layout-xlarge in res folder . and put your xmls into those folder and then change whatever you want to do with text view and anything

Answer (score -3):

Go to your xml file and add textsize as:

```
android:textSize="20sp"
```

This will increase your font size